# Prepended input in Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm Trying to get my Prepended Input working but i'm not getting it right somehow.
I'm on Rails 4. (If this matters)

**My Current Input looks like so**->

```
<!-- Email Input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true, label: false %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And i want to add the Prepend** ->

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Could anyone help me compine those two ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
<div class="control-group"> 
   <label class="control-label">Email</label>
   <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">@</span>
      <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true, label: false %>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Almost, you have to put the input-prepend to the controls class.. But still when i do it there is a huge spacing between the label and the input.